# updating reference field using generics sObject

Tags: apex, sobject, relationships, generics

I am trying to perform upsert on `opportunity` based on `external Id`. I am building the opportunity objects based on `sObject` as I am using that function for other objects too.

Now `Opportunity` object contains the reference to `Account` and it has `BasicId__c` field which I am trying to update.

in order to dynamically update the `Opportunity` data and `Account` reference filed I have written the following code.

```
 SObject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity').newSObject();

 //for normal Opportunity field (this works fine)
 sObj.put('Name','John');
 sObj.put('OfficePhone__c','9998889890');

 //for reference field update `Account.BasicId__c`

 SObject sRefObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').newSObject();
 sRefObj.put('BasicId__c','44322');
 sObj.putSObject('Account',sRefObj);
```

Now, when I perform an upsert after casting `sobj` to `Opportunity` it throws following error

> INVALID_FIELD: Field name provided, BasicId__c is not an External ID
>   or indexed field for Account

Not sure how would i able to update the reference field.

***Kindly note***

`BasicId__c` is not the external Id in `Account`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do this the field `BasicId__c` should be an External Id. Also, the parent record with that particular External Id should be present in the database.

1. If you put the account in opportunity using `sObj.putSObject('Account',sRefObj);` it doesn't mean that it will update/insert account too. You need to put an account with the External Id field populated in it. Also, No other fields are allowed put, while you perform the DML. So when you insert opportunity, it will just update the account reference in it by searching the account using the populated external id field. **Note you can not use any field other than external Id in this method, not even ID.**
2. Now, what if you don't have an external id field. you want to update/insert the account update it separately before inserting/updating the opportunity.
   So you need to put a Salesforce Id of an Account into Opportunity.

   `sObj.putSObject('AccountId',account.Id);`

Comment: but it is not , it is just the normal field like `First Name`  which I want to update , any alternative

Comment: Suppose I need to update the `Name` file in the account then? I can not convert that into external id

Comment: I guess You cannot convert the name field to an external id.
first, insert the accounts, create the map of account the name field and id, then use that map to fill the accountId field on an opportunities.

Comment: @Hunt I have updated my answer I hope you can understand that. Also, it's always better to put a comment mentioning what is wrong in the answer or what you don't understand before you put -1.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update a related object in a DML operation like this. You need to update the account and opportunity separately. The syntax you've attempted to use is used to set a lookup field by an External ID (i.e. your code is attempting to set AccountId to an Account that matches an External Id in the BasicId__c field). In other words, you need at minimum two DML operations here in order to update both records, since you can't mix data types in an upsert call.